# Info on building Spark with "(CDH 4.2.0), yarn (Hadoop 2.4.0)" with Hive?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, hive

I'm planning to build Spark to spin off on EC2. The default spark_ec2.py downloads a prebuilt package (1 for Hadoop 1.0.4 and 2 for CDH 4.2.0, yarn (Hadoop 2.4.0)) but it is built without '-Phive -Phive-thriftserver' options. Mostly I need to use Hive UDFs and it has to be built from source. (I'd need YARN too as 'Hive on Spark supports Spark on YARN mode as default.')

The 'Building Spark' page illustrates a number of examples and it seems to be a mix of

#### Cloudera CDH 4.2.0 with MapReduce v1

`mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0 -Phadoop-1 -DskipTests clean package`

and

#### Apache Hadoop 2.4.X with Hive 13 support

`mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package`

(source: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html)

At the moment, the following is what I can think of

`mvn -Pyarn -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0-mr1-cdh4.2.0 -Phadoop-1 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package`

Can anyone inform if the above is correct or let me know any other resource that I can learn from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstood that `--hadoop-major-version` has 3 options:

- "1" for Hadoop 1.0.4
- "2" for CDH 4.2.0 (mr1)
- "yarn" for Hadoop 2.4.0

I used `spark.ami.hvm.v14 (ami-35b1885c)` and was able to build successfully by the following.

`./make-distribution.sh --name spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4-hive-yarn --tgz -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Psparkr -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests`